# Ising model on torus

Tags: statistical-mechanics, ising-model

It's expected that the pressure of the Ising model on a $d$-dimensional discrete torus with side length $L$ converges to the mean-field Ising model pressure as the dimension $d$ goes to infinity. Is there a rigorous proof for this fact?  Intuitively this is indeed true. Thanks for any references.

Comment: What do you mean by pressure in the Ising model?

Comment: I don't think the torus has anything to do with this.  It is just conventional to set the Ising model on a torus as a convenient way of choosing boundary conditions.  In the thermodynamic limit, these boundary conditions should be irrelevant to the behavior of the system.  So the question is really:  Does the Ising model behave according to the predictions of mean field theory as the dimensionality $d$ goes to infinity?

Comment: @Zack, the log partition function, also known as free energy

Comment: @Buzz, Yes, I will say that's exactly the motivation for this question. The torus setting is just for convenience, directly working on lattice could be technical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this was first proved (as far as I know) by Colin J. Thompson in his paper *Ising model in the high density limit*, published in [Communication in Mathematical Physics **36**(4), 255-262, 1974](https://projecteuclid.org/journalArticle/Download?urlId=cmp%2F1103859770).

There are also similar results for the magnetization, as well as inequalities relating these quantities on finite-dimensional lattices and in the mean-field approximation. You can also look at the (brief) discussion and the references given in Sections 2.5.4 and 3.10.2 in [our book](https://www.unige.ch/math/folks/velenik/smbook) for additional information on this topic.

There is also a discussion (with some proofs) of such issues in Section II.14 of [Simon's book](https://press.princeton.edu/books/hardcover/9780691636436/the-statistical-mechanics-of-lattice-gases-volume-i).